# How to stop cmake add wxjpeg.lib to visual studio project?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, wxwidgets

I have a project that uses both OpenCv and wxWidgets in a static library. These two libraries have definitions for jpeg and hence are generating conflicts during compilation.

As I am not using jpeg which is inside wxwidget, I would like to remove this library from my application. I tested my application and if I remove this library manually from MSVC poroject, it works well.

In cmake I have this line to add wxwidgets to my project:

```
set(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION msvc)
find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base adv   REQUIRED)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
```

How can I instruct cmake not to add wxjpeg.lib to the requested linked libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation to this cmake module ([link](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindwxWidgets.html)) I would say that adding

```
set(wxWidgets_EXCLUDE_COMMON_LIBRARIES TRUE)
```

before using the `find_package` command would be enough to exclude  `wxjpeg.lib`. Since this also excludes other common libraries (e.g. `png`), you may have to explicitly include more in your call to `find_package`

```
find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base adv png REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Thanks, but after doing this, I am getting this error: Error 44 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol wx_png_create_read_struct referenced in function "public: virtual bool __cdecl wxPNGHandler::LoadFile(class wxImage *,class wxInputStream &,bool,int)" (?LoadFile@wxPNGHandler@@UEAA_NPEAVwxImage@@AEAVwxInputStream@@_NH@Z) C:\MyData\SourceCodes\Build\wxmsw30ud_core.lib(imagpng.obj)